# How to develop an IME (Input Method Editor) Related Text Service Framework in Metro mode?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, ime, text-services-framework

"Text Services Framework" How to implement my IME program in windows8 Metro mode.

Answer (score 1):

I am searching for the same and I am still researching.

To help, here is the sample code information. if you have visual studio then its in your sample zip and within that in 'international' folder:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x02zb6d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

I have compiled the code though and its level 3 code i.e. development of your own controls.

here is another link that might help you in when you start actual development:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/tsf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1755

Good luck!